# Allowing website user to browse a server folder

Tags: javascript, html

A simple HTML code snippet allows you to browse your own files:

```
<input type="file" value="Browse">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

But how do I let the user browse server folders, and only particular ones therein? (I'd hate to have someone deleting my root...)

I've done some searching around, but immediate search terms like "user browse server directory" return scanty references.

Comment: You don't... if someone can browse files on the server they can see your code - that's a major security risk!

Comment: You can usually give these FileUpload controls urls if images and such if that helps?

Comment: I guess you're right. I think I'll give the user HTML radio options instead, as I won't be changing these files any time soon.